# Keep UIKeyboard up while reloading UITableView section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to know if there is a way to keep `UIKeyboard` up while reloading section in `UITableView`? I have `UITextField` inside a *header view* of `UITableView`'s *section*. Typing into this `UITextField` fires action that requires a *section* to be updated (reloaded).

As a result of calling `[tableView reloadSections:...]` the keyboard hides itself, because `UITextField` loses it's `firstResponder` status.

I would like to achieve similar effect like when using `UISearchBar` component in `UITableView`.

Thanks!

Comment: but the UIkeyboard is keeping up  by itself unless you do the opposite with code programmatically

Comment: Below solution is not worked for anyone then go with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535068/keyboardhide-on-reload-tableview-or-on-reload-particular-row-or-on-insert-and-de/55536361#55536361

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reload, everything will get refreshed. When that happens, the current first responder is resigned and the keyboard is animated out. To avoid that you need to no reload...

You would need to update the visible cells directly and use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to make changes to the number of rows the table is managing. In this way the section won't be reloaded and you will avoid any cell animations / refreshing of views.

Comment: thanks. I've thought of that, but I don't really know how to implement ``insertRows...`` and ``deleteRows..`` methods for *searching-like* behaviour. Basically my ``UITextField`` acts like a search box. Any tips/directions?

Comment: The cause of the change in section data isn't important, what is important is the result. If you have no existing rows in the section then you would call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` with an array of index paths for all rows that are new (all of them) (and delete all the old rows if required)

Comment: Finally, I gave up and implement ``insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`` and ``deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:``. Thanks for showing me the way!