# Keyboardhide on reload tableview or on reload particular row or on insert and delete

Tags: ios, keyboard

i have tableview cell in which there is another tableview in which i have textfield and if i change value of textfield, i need to reload table view or reload that that particular row but it hides the keyboard as table is reload. Any idea to keep the keyboard as it is ???

i have try following stackoverflow suggestions but it's not work for me.

[Keep UIKeyboard up while reloading UITableView section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390533/keep-uikeyboard-up-while-reloading-uitableview-section)

Also try following codes.

```
[self.tblADMEDesign beginUpdates];
[self.tblADMEDesign insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tblADMEDesign deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tblADMEDesign endUpdates];
```

```
[self.tblADMEDesign beginUpdates];
[self.tblADMEDesign endUpdates];
```

```
[self.tblADMEDesign beginUpdates];
[self.tblADMEDesign reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tblADMEDesign endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390533/keep-uikeyboard-up-while-reloading-uitableview-section) is the best solution to keep the keyboard open while reloading `UITableView` content.

If it is not working for you then quick hacks always work.

Please follow the below steps.

- Take one dummy `UITextField` into your view `controller(Storyboard)`
- Give `constraints` as you like(Doesn't matter)
- Keep hidden dummy `UITextField` always from the storyboard.
- Take the `outlet` of the hidden dummy `UITextField` into the class file.
- Now time for the hack before `reloadData()` just call `txtDummy.becomeFirstResponder()`

Refer to below code I have done to the resolved issue.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

      @IBOutlet weak var txtDummy: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            tblView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 10
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
            cell.txtField?.text = "text"
            return cell
        }
    
        @IBAction func reloadtable(){
            txtDummy.becomeFirstResponder()
            tblView.reloadData()
            //Perform other operation after some delay
        }
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of Storyboard]

Refer to the attached source code of the demo application. If any further help is required.

[Source Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18FX5TeYAmLxrIKnbp1CBhznUskvgdqlY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have tried a lot of solutions, your solution was the best! hahah

Comment: Thank you!!  Hacks always work 